# Clicking through to new site returns error "java.net.UnknownHostException:"

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have  a JMeter script which quite happily logins to a session and then needs to click through to a new site as part of a single sign on test. If I do this manually a new site with a new URL is opened. If I do this via JMeter I'm getting a "java.net.UnknownHostException:" error.

I suspect this has something to do with cookie management but I am not 100% sure. I do have a cookie manager for the Thread Group.

Update: I experience the same thing when I record the session using the Test Script Recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means JMeter does not know your website.

Most probably it's a proxy issue, you need to provide to JMeter what your browser already has in terms of configuration.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Is it possible to configure this in the gui somehow?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance